# phpstorm autocomplete & ctrl+click not recognising nested vars/methods

Tags: php, autocomplete, ide, phpstorm

[image]

`amrManager` doc:

[image]
[image]

As you can see from the snip, phpstorm sees the methods/obj from the class instance but when accessing the next depth level of methods from the objects, it does not recognise them :( and this makes development really hard as I am coming from a Java background. When using the same code in Netbeans it recognised them as expected but not in phpstorm.

Surely this can be set somehow but I can't find how.
Also I am using a Symfony project.

Comment: What is `armManager` -- how it is defined/created/accessed? What do you see when you `Ctrl+Q` (View | Quick Documentation) on it?

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot -- IDE does not know what type `armManager` is. no surprise that it marks those methods as unknown. Please show screenshot/code of how `armManager` is defined in your code (BaseArmController).

Comment: I'm not using neither NetBeans or Symfony myself .. and cannot really answer your last question. I can only guess that they have better/specific support for Symfony framework. **BTW** -- do you use Symfony plugin in PhpStorm?? Should help! **In any case**: adding **simple** PHPDoc will solve your issue: `/** @var MyArmManagerClass */` `protected $armManager;`  (use correct class name, of course).

Comment: Yes the Symfony plugin is installed and working. Then I guess there is no other option than to insert docblocks where needed. Post your answer so I can mark it. And thank you for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on how `armManager` field is declared and what PhpStorm knows about it. Best result will always be when proper PHPDoc comment will be used or when type can be figured from default value.

As we an see <kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd> (View | Quick Documentation) shows that IDE does not know much about (what type) `armManager` (`protected $armManager;` does not tell much indeed).

Based on your code, adding this simple PHPDoc comment will resolve your issue (plus added benefit on self-documentation):

```
/** @var MyArmManagerClass Optional description here */
protected $armManager;
```

*(use correct class name, of course)*